# Error al agregar WebForms en proyecto MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp, webforms

Me encuentro con el siguiente error al momento de abrir una vista que he creado en mi proyecto MVC 5 ASP.NET, el archivo de la vista es .aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Asistencias.aspx.cs" Inherits="Visitantes.Views.Informes.Asistencias" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

También he creado un controlador para llamar a esta vista, el controlador es el siguiente:

```
using Syc.Visitantes.Aplicacion.Controladores;
using Syc.Visitantes.Dominio.Entidades;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Visitantes.Controllers
{
    public class InformesController : BaseController
    {

        public ActionResult Asistencias()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Esta vista la estoy creando de esta manera para poder usar el ReportViewer en ella, ya que estoy haciendo unos reportes con Reporting Services. El error que me muestra es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible combinar WebForms con MVC ASP.NET?

Comment: Por que motivo usas ASP.NET MVC 5 y quieres usar ASPX? xd

Comment: Porque según el tutorial que conseguí para agregar reportes con ReportViewer dice que se debe agregar en un WebForm el reporte, pero si existe otra forma me gustaría saber